# Live USB for Multiple OS's

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, ntfs, ext4

i currently have 4 USBs with different Live OS's on them; is it possible to put them all on a single stick with a boot loader (OS chooser) so i'm not so cluttered?  and how.  3 are linux based, one is windows, so i'd need at last two file systems i'm sure.

Comment: There are a few solutions for that. The most popular is probably Multisystem. https://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/).